# Search and replace string in 2D Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, search, replace

Teaching myself swift, so complete noob here, but I'm far into a project and just know there must be an easier way to achieve something.

I have a 2D array:

```
var shopArray = [
["theme":"default","price":0,"owned":true,"active":true,"image":UIImage(named: "defaultImage")!,"title":"BUY NOW"],
["theme":"red","price":1000,"owned":false,"active":false,"image":UIImage(named: "redImage")!,"title":"BUY NOW"],
["theme":"blue","price":2000,"owned":false,"active":false,"image":UIImage(named: "blueImage")!,"title":"BUY NOW"],
["theme":"pool","price":3000,"owned":true,"active":false,"image":UIImage(named: "blueImage")!,"title":"BUY NOW"],
["theme":"line","price":4000,"owned":false,"active":false,"image":UIImage(named: "lineImage")!,"title":"BUY NOW"],
["theme":"neon","price":5000,"owned":false,"active":false,"image":UIImage(named: "lineImage")!,"title":"BUY NOW"]]
```

Where I simply want to create a function that runs and search for all the **"owned"** keys and make them all **"false"**.

How do you search and replace in Arrays / 2D Arrays.  More specifiaclly, what should the func look like?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried, please share your code. And you should consider replacing your inner collection with a struct that holds the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a 2D array, you have an Array of Dictionaries.

You can set all of the values for the `owned` keys by iterating the indices of the Array and updating the values:

```
shopArray.indices.forEach { shopArray[$0]["owned"] = false }
```

That is the functional way to do it.  You could also do the same operation with a `for` loop:

```
for idx in shopArray.indices {
    shopArray[idx]["owned"] = false
}
```

Comment: Dude!  You rock.  I used your first option and it worked like a charm! 

Thanks... :)  Now I know it's a Array OF Dictionaries.  

I was messing around with your code to see if it could work in a normal array too, but no joy. 

How would you do the same thing in this example to replace "BUY NOW" with "IT's YOURS"?

var collections = ["IT'S YOURS","BUY NOW","BUY NOW","BUY NOW","BUY NOW","BUY NOW"]

Comment: `let newArray = collections.map { $0 == "BUY NOW" ? "IT'S YOURS" : $0 }`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to loopthrough the array replacing the approriate element.

```
var i = 0
for x in shopArray {
    var y = x
    y["owned"] = false
    shopArray.remove(at: i)
    shopArray.insert(y, at: i)
    i = i + 1
}
```

or you could use a while loop to do the same with less code lines.

```
var y = 0
while y < shopArray.count {
    shopArray[y].updateValue(false, forKey: "owned")
    y += 1
}
```

There is proably somthing doable with .contains, but I'm not sure you need that toachive the result you mention above. Play around in a play ground in xcode and try a few different options without doing anything that might cause issues in your project.